# Как разрешить трафик приложению?

Tags: linux, сеть, iptables, ufw

Я хочу по умолчанию запретить весь трафик и выдавать разрешения на доступ в интернет конкретным приложениям.

```
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

А теперь, у меня есть исполняемый файл `/home/*/.local/bin/Obsidian/Obsidian-1.0.3.AppImage` и Я хочу разрешить ему и только ему трафик.

Как это сделать через iptables Я не смог найти, так как iptables даже не знает что такое http. Пробовал поискать про ufw, он знает что такое http, а вот примеров как бинарнику разрешение выдать не увидел.

Разве нет такой возможности?

Comment: без опыта и лезть сразу в блокировку приложений? тем более упакованных... ну не знаю. может начать сначала с правил по портам?

Comment: Прямо такого (привязки правил фаерволла к исполняемом файлу) нет. Но вы можете попробовать почитать про cgroups.

Comment: @eri открытым портом может воспользоваться кто угодно.

Comment: нет, только приложение, открывшее его

Comment: @user_587 ещё selinux можно.

Comment: приложение AFWall+ для андроида умеет управлять разрешениями для приложений, а на Debian like такого нет :-( и вопрос мне еще минусуете. бред какой-то. не умеете и не хотите уметь управлять разрешениями гибко, а вопросы по теме парицаются. Б-безопасность.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно изолировать сеть для конкретного приложения, то проще запустить его в контейнере. Потом задача сводится к настройке фаервола на forward при стандартной сети или cgroups при хостовой сети.

Аналогом виндового разрешения приложению на доступ к сети я вижу политики [selinux](https://serverfault.com/a/367840/183600) или более дружелюбного apparmor, у которого даже есть десктопные уведомления https://wiki.debian.org/AppArmor/HowToUse#Desktop_notifications

Comment: есть виндовые фаерволы которые запрашивают разрешение когда приложение первый раз просится в сеть. и Я даю это разрешение или не даю. вот мне нужно тоже самое только в линуксе.

Comment: а могу Я вас попросить подсказать как установить политику для приложений без профиля? если профиля нет, то все запрещено. все что нахожу описывает установку и настройку конкретному приложению, а про политику по умолчанию не нахожу.

Comment: https://github.com/Kicksecure/apparmor-profile-everything похоже, что нет.

Comment: честно я только с профилями астры возился для защищенного сервера недавно. аппармор изучал 10 лет назад - вспоминать надо.